# Web application into IBM Websphere portal 6.0

Tags: java, struts, websphere, portlet, websphere-portal

We have developed standalone web application using struts & jsp. But the user need that application should be hosted inside IBM Websphere Portal 6.0 inside new portlet. Is there any feature is available to show the application Page / include web application into portal. Any Idea on how we have achieve that? Let me know if any other informations are required.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to rewrite the entire application in portlets, there is the Web Application Integrator you can try to use. It will let you pull another application into Portal while giving it the same theme (aka look and feel) as the Portal.

Link to Web Application Intergrator on Lotus Greenhouse
https://greenhouse.lotus.com/plugins/plugincatalog.nsf/assetDetails.xsp?action=editDocument&documentId=31AC15EF8BF546DF85257700005C50BE

Otherwise to get this running in Portal you will need to rewrite the application using the portlet spec. Struts library is a supported development path in Portal 7 & 8 but I haven't worked with V6 to know what kind of support you'd get there. Some simple google searches should get you some tutorials on building portlets with struts.

If at all possible try to convince whoever is asking for this to upgrade to at least Portal 7. As Udo mentioned, Portal 6 has aged quite a bit and there may not be much support available from IBM if something goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [struts sample](https://greenhouse.lotus.com/catalog/home_full.xsp?fProduct=WebSphere%20Portal&fSearchValue=struts#) in the Solution Catalog. If you ask me however, I'd call it a dead end. Struts 1 is EOL and WebSphere Portal 6.0 as well.